# SQL: Sub query in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I want to select certain values from one tables based on result of the other for the most recent 7 results.

**tbLimit :** `SELECT * from limits where id_device = ?`

```
minTemp|maxTemp|minHum|maxHum
10      20      40     60
```

**tbSensor :** `SELECT temperature, humidity, smoke, reading_time FROM sensor WHERE id_device = $id_device order by reading_time desc limit 7`

```
temperature| humidity | smoke | reading_time
 15.20       30.20      555.12   15:44:52
 25.40       54.40     1900.51   15:40:31
 and so on for the first 7 results
```

I want to form an array containing each value that matches the conditions in the first table along with the reading time.

For example: an array with temperatures < minTemp with their readings time

Any advice on this one?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. SImplify, perhaps LIMIT 3 is enough? [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for that.  
In the future, I will consider your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select s.id_device, s.reading_time, s.smoke,
    l.minTemp, s.temperature, l.maxTemp,
    l.minHum, s.humidity, l.maxHum
from tbSensor s
inner join tbLimit l on l.id_device = s.id_device
where (
       s.temperature < l.minTemp
    or s.temperature > l.maxTemp
    or s.humidity < l.minHum
    or s.humidity > l.maxHum
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a JOIN, as in:

```
select
  s.*
from sensor s
join limits l on s.temperature not between l.minTemp and l.maxTemp
              or s.humidity not between l.minHum and l.maxHum
where l.id_device = ?
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I want the values for outside that interval

Comment: @reyork Then use `NOT BETWEEN`. Changed it for completeness.

Comment: Thank you, really apreciate it!